# Too many diff.tool values

Tags: git

[image]

I am trying to use beyond compare with git as my diff tool (probably merge later). I've tried tutorials from [Tim's Blog](http://cfmumbojumbo.com/cf/index.cfm/coding/git-using-a-different-comparison-tool/) and [Beyond Compare Website](http://cfmumbojumbo.com/cf/index.cfm/coding/git-using-a-different-comparison-tool/)

Now I have too many copies of `diff.tool` variables. I deleted everything in my config files, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig` and current git repo I am in.

Is there a way to delete all the variables? If so where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is also the global config

```
~/.git/config
```

and then per repo in

```
yourrepo/.git/config
```

you can specify which config with `--local`, `--global` or `--system` when you issue the config command. `--local` is implied if you don't specify scope explicitly.

Comment: They are found in global however, I deleted everything in that config file. How can I find the path for the global config file? There might be more than one??

Comment: there is only one per user and it exist in your home dir (~). `ls -A` to see . files.

Comment: Woah when I type `~` it says my drive `z:/` which is comprised of `.gitconfig`, `.gitk`, and `_viminfo`. Yes, I see the multiple variables. Thanks! Do you how I made the `z:/` my home directory. Shouldn't it be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig` as my home directory?

Comment: no. that's the system level. it will be in effect for all users.